# Overflow error in query with no calculations

Tags: sql, postgresql, overflow, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run the following query on `Amazon Redshift`:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fms.created_at) AS YEAR,
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fms.created_at) AS MONTH,
             EXTRACT(DAY FROM fms.created_at) AS DAY,
             EXTRACT(DOW FROM fms.created_at) AS DOW,
             fms.member_id,
             fms.user_role,
             fms.artifact_id,
             fms.context_eid,
             fms.visitor_id,
             gi.city,
             gi.country_long,
             gi.domain,
             gi.isp,
             gi.region,
             gi.zipcode,
             fms.client_ip,
             fms.created_at,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY fms.member_id ORDER BY fms.member_id,fms.created_at) AS RowNum
      FROM ads.table1 fms
        JOIN auth.table2 ON fms.client_ip = gi.client_ip
      WHERE fms.member_id NOT IN (SELECT memberid FROM auth.table3 WHERE roleid = 25)
      AND   fms.member_id <> 2
      ORDER BY fms.member_id,
               fms.created_at)
```

and getting the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM fms.created_at) AS YEAR,
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM fms.created_at) AS MONTH,
           ...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647)
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647)
  code:      1207
  context:   Value: '656763985952244500', Character: '9'
  query:     138816
  location:  :0
  process:   query5_43 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------;

Execution time: 11.6s
1 statement failed.
```

I'm not quite sure why I am getting this error because I am not doing any calculation prone to overflow. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statements would be useful.

Comment: I would post them, but I don't have the admin view to generate the DDLs.

Comment: The "context" line seems to suggest that it's not a calculation causing the overflow, but a string->integer conversion from the value `'656763985952244500'`. Are any of your `id` columns declared as strings, and do they contain this value? If so, the integer comparisons in your query (e.g. `member_id <> 2`) are probably forcing this conversion.

Comment: As per @NickBarnes comment, but the ids could also be BIGINT. Try something like `member_id <> CAST(2 AS BIGINT)` or `member_id <> '2'`